# Get the value of a variable with with the same name as the value of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, eval

I have a jQuery widget that outputs a table of contents when invoked.

I'd like to give users the oppurtunity to specify the ID of each individal element within the contents (`listElementID: 'contents-{index}'` by default), so I've come up with a function within the widget to achieve this.

There criteria for this is quite simple -

1. Replace `{index}` with the value of the `index` parameter that is passed to the function.
2. Replace and other instance of `{.*}` (I.e. `{whatever}` with the matching widget option `this.options.whatever`.

I can extract required variables from `this.options.listElementID`, but I can't seem to find a way to then get the value of the matching parameter/option.

I've tried to do this using `eval()` (sorry!), but if for example `varName = 'index';`, `eval('varName');` simply returns **index**, not the value of the `index` parameter.

How can I correct my code?

```
_getContnetsLineID : function(index){

    var vars = (this.options.listElementID.match(/{.*}/g) || []),
        ID = this.options.listElementID;

    for(var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++){

        var varName,    // The name of the variable to grab the value from
            value;      // The value to replace the placehoder with

        varName = vars[i].replace('{', '').replace('}', '');    // Remove the '{' and '}' characters from the 'varName'

        if(varName == 'index'){ // Attempt to grab the value from a variable that matches the string 'varName'
            value = eval('varName');    
        } else {
            value = eval('this.options.varName');
        }

        ID = ID.replace(vars[i], value);    // Replace the placeholder with the appropriate value

    }

    return ID;

} // _getContnetsLineID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```js
this.options = {
    listElementID: "foobar-{index}-{whatever}",
    whatever: "hi"
};

_getLineID = function (index) {
    return this.options.listElementID.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function (_, name) {
        return name === 'index' ? index : this.options[name];
    });
}

document.write(_getLineID(25));
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick.  I had to add `var t = this;` and change `this.options[name];` to `t.options[name];` (I was getting an undefined variable error), but this code achieves exactly what I was looking for.