# Recursively replace placeholder text with the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Earlier today I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175528/get-the-value-of-a-variable-with-with-the-same-name-as-the-value-of-a-string/35175615#35175615), which was very quickly answered to my satisfaction.

In the time since a new requirement has come to light, and I now need to replace a variable placeholder with it's value **recursivly**

Here is an example of my code as it currently stands.  The full widget is available in [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mYtsrHLx) -

```
$.widget('custom.contents', {

    options : {

        singleID    : 'content-{index}',
        linkID      : 'link_to_{singleID}'

    }, // options

    _create : function(){

        console.log(this._getOption(25, 'linkID'));

    }, // _create

    _getOption : function(index, option){

        var t = this;   // The object

        var optionValue = this.options[option].replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function(_, name){
            return name === 'index' ? index : t.options[name];
        });

        return optionValue;

    } // _getOption

});
```

If I were to include `console.log(this._getOption(25, 'linkID'));` the output value would be `link_to_foobar-{index}`.

Before that value is returned, I'd like to **recursively** run the `_getOption()` function to ensure that all values enclosed within `{}` are replaced.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add live demo.

Comment: When the function is called as `_getOption()`, `this` inside the function is `window` object.

Comment: @Tushar I think we can safely assume that both the `options` and the function `_getOption` are inside the same object ;)

Comment: @Tushar - They are within the same object, I'm adjusting my example to make that more obvious now...

Comment: @Tushar - Example updated, and I've added the full code to a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mYtsrHLx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a loop using your pattern, and while it continues to match, continue to do the replace:

```
_getOption = function(index, option){

    var opt = this.options[option];
    var pattern = /{(.+?)}/g;
    while(pattern.test(opt)){
      opt = opt.replace(pattern, function(_, name){   // Search for all instances of '{(.+?)}'...
          return name === 'index' ? index : t.options[name];                          // ...Replace all instance of '{(.+?)}' with the value of the associated variable
      });
    }

    return opt;

} // _getOption
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ng1bhda/1/

Comment: `opt.match(pattern)` ==> `pattern.test(opt)`

Comment: @Tushar - is there a preformance differece, or is it personal preference?

Comment: @DavidGard `match` is used to extract string, `test` is used to check if string contains a pattern.

Comment: @DavidGard If the key `index` is fixed, I've [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/2bgmzdmh/) for you. Let me know how that works.

Comment: `opt.match` works as it returns an array of matches or null. However @Tushar is right, it's better as `pattern.test` - answer updated